# F4-key mysteriously reassigned

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

In the middle of today, my `F4` key started producing the letter `p`, without my conscious acting and I can't seem to revert this change. Whenever I press `F4`, `p` appears instead. How can I change this back?

Pressing `p`, `xev` returns:

```
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x150, subw 0x0, time 581565, (696,-17), root:(698,55),
    state 0x0, keycode 33 (keysym 0x70, p), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (70) "p"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (70) "p"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x150, subw 0x0, time 581605, (696,-17), root:(698,55),
    state 0x0, keycode 33 (keysym 0x70, p), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (70) "p"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Pressing `F4`, `xev` returns:

```
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x150, subw 0x0, time 582298, (696,-17), root:(698,55),
    state 0x0, keycode 33 (keysym 0x70, p), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (70) "p"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (70) "p"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x150, subw 0x0, time 582318, (696,-17), root:(698,55),
    state 0x0, keycode 33 (keysym 0x70, p), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (70) "p"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

As far as I'm concerned, both keys appear to me as one and the same key. Where can I revert or change such low-level behavior?

**Update:** I plugged in an external keyboard for which `F4` works as expected. So... is my keyboard broken?

**Update:** While in GRUB, before the kernel starts, `F4` simply does nothing as opposed to produce a `p`. To me, this can only mean that it's an OS problem.

**Update:** In the ttys (1 to 3, 5 and 6 (I can't access the fourth through `Ctrl`-`Alt`-`F4`)), `F4` equally produces `p`.

Comment: In a text console, run `showkey` and press `p` and `F4`. What's the output? Also check the kernel logs to see if there's anything keyboard-related. Another thing to check would be to boot from another operating system (e.g. a bootable Linux USB image) and see what `F4` does there.

Comment: Same output for both: `keycode  25 press
keycode  25 release`, no matter which of the two keys I press.

Comment: I also realised this happens on Windows as well... which exceeds my mind. I will however migrate it to general SO as it's no longer unix-specific.

Comment: Unless this is a programmable keyboard, I blame a speck of dust or other contaminant in the keyboard. Try shaking it; or in desperation, wash it and wait several months (yes, it takes very long) for it to dry.

Comment: Tried that and also removed the key and cleaned up below it. However, GRUB treats the key as expected. It thus appears like it would be working initially but then get new behavior through some system driver or something.

Comment: What kind of keyboard is it, what exact model? If it's USB, one thing that Windows and Linux share is that they have their own driver, whereas Grub relies on the BIOS. But I have no idea why one key would return a different code when the keyboard is not used in legacy mode.

Comment: It's a laptop that I'm using: HP Elitebook 6930p. Can't seem to find a specific model number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a long shot, but this can occasionally solve mysterious problems with laptop BIOSes. Switch off the computer, unplug it and remove the battery. Wait a bit, then plug it on. It's possible that some memory used by the BIOS has become corrupted and a complete power cycle will reinitialize it.

Comment: I removed the battery over night and unplugged it and as far as I can tell, everything is back to normal now!! :-) Thanks a lot, this really bothered me!